# Can we know what gradle runs internal commands to build an android application?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am just curious and wanted to know about gradle the set of commands it runs internally to build an APK.

Is that possible to know where I can read about this? I tried to pass the debug and info flag while doing 'assembleDebug' task but couldn't get any much information what commands it runs internally.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If any information is required to answer this please post will clarify your doubt.

Comment: Android Gradle Plugin is open source, but AFAIK most "commands" are simply implemented as Java code not by calling an external tool. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I like to add the [task tree plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) to my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "2.1.1"
}
```

You can then run the following which will show a task tree for the "build" task

```
gradle build taskTree
```

For a java project the output looks like

```
:build
+--- :assemble
|    \--- :jar
|         \--- :classes
|              +--- :compileJava
|              \--- :processResources
\--- :check
     \--- :test
          +--- :classes
          |    +--- :compileJava
          |    \--- :processResources
          \--- :testClasses
               +--- :compileTestJava
               |    \--- :classes
               |         +--- :compileJava
               |         \--- :processResources
               \--- :processTestResources
```

Comment: I wanted to know about the commands for example, if we say "Process resources" what is that gradle is running in this step?

Comment: The gradle docs for the java plugin have a [tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) section which outlines the task names and their types. Perhaps the android docs have similar?

Comment: But every task is running some commands to complete that task can we know about that?

Comment: Click through to the docs for each task (eg [ProcessResources docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.html) or [ProcessResources javadocs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.html)). Perhaps find the source code for each task (eg [ProcessResources.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/platforms/jvm/language-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/language/jvm/tasks/ProcessResources.java))